# Create a 2D list out of 1D list

Tags: python, matrix

I am a bit new to Python and I want to convert a 1D list to a 2D list, given the `width` and `length` of this `matrix`.

Say I have a `list=[0,1,2,3]` and I want to make a `2 by 2` matrix of this list.

How can I get `matrix [[0,1],[2,3]]` `width`=2, `length`=2 out of the `list`?

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3636344/1947535

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
In [53]: l = [0,1,2,3]

In [54]: def to_matrix(l, n):
    ...:     return [l[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(l), n)]

In [55]: to_matrix(l,2)
Out[55]: [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Another example of why I love Python!  Thanks @root!

Comment: `xrange` was renamed to `range` in python 3

Answer (score 14):

I think you should use numpy, which is purpose-built for working with matrices/arrays, rather than a list of lists.  That would look like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_ = [0,1,2,3]
>>> a = np.array(list_).reshape(2,2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 2)
```

Avoid calling a variable `list` as it shadows the built-in name.

Comment: why is using numpy better than root's approach?

Comment: It depends on what you need 2D structure for, but when you are working with matrices in almost any way numpy will be more efficient, convenient, and flexible.

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1000000 into shape (2,2)

Answer (score 1):

not as elegant and pretty specific to yours, but you create 2 lists (every other integer) and zip/list them back together.

```
full_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in full_list:
  if i % 2 == 0:
    list1.append(i)
  else:
    list2.append(i)

zip_list = zip(list1, list2)
done = list(zip_list)

output:
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```