# how to display 3 * 3 matrix in python without Numpy function

Tags: python, list

```
( with the given inputs L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] )
```

how to display 3 * 3 matrix in python without Numpy function

Comment: Have you tried creating this matrix? What code have you written?

Comment: not this question, i mean 3 dimensional matrix(3*3 martices) with simple answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681687/12309808):

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L = [L[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(L), 3)]
print(L)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: can you write pseudo code for this

Comment: What pseudocode?

Comment: for above code can you write pseudo code (i mean steps in an algorithm)

Comment: I have given u the the python code. And the code is also pretty much understandable. So why don't u give it a go instead of asking me to do it?